# primary key generator whenever insert is used

Tags: java, mysql

How do I need to create table primary id key generator?

```
 <int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter id="jdbcOutbound"
                                       channel="feed"
                                       data-source="dataSource"
                                       query="INSERT INTO queue(TITLE, AUTHOR, PUBLISHEDDATE)
                                       values(:payload[title], :payload[author], :payload[publishedDate])"/>
```

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS queue (
  ID integer identity primary key,
  TITLE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  AUTHOR VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PUBLISHEDDATE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

That whenever `query` inserts payload to table, ID would be generated automatically (1,2,3...) ?

Comment: Next time, please, be sure that context of your question is really relevant: Spring really does nothing with MySQL and scheme-specific tasks are even out of Java scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS queue (
  ID integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  TITLE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  AUTHOR VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PUBLISHEDDATE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

primary key generator whenever insert is used

**its 2 ways....**

**1. while creating for table it will create primary key.**

**Ex:-** create  table Customers1
(
CustomerID  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
CustomerName varchar(23) not null,
ContactName varchar (25) not null,
Address varchar (25),
City varchar (25),
PostalCode integer (23),
c varchar(24),
PRIMARY KEY ( CustomerID )
)

2. while creating index by default only it is created.

**Ex:-**  Create Index IndexName ;